# Populate a new table in Nested for loop in r

Tags: r

I have two tables:
`Table1` contains time series for a year:

`Date       year  month  hour   value 
01/01/2020  2020   1       0    1800
01/01/2020  2020   1       1    1300
01/01/2020  2020   1       2    400
01/01/2020  2020   1       3    1235
01/01/2020  2020   1       4    120.014
01/01/2020  2020   1       5    812.54`

and so on.

I have another `Table2` in which a fixed distribution `Factor` is given in a table for a certain `Name` (Country)

`Name   Factor
UK      0.003
BE      0.018
DE      0.28
FR      0.43`

Now I want to create a another dataframe/table `Table3` which will be populated by nested loop of two tables `Table1` and `Table2` in such a way that
the `Value` of each `Hour` from `Table1` will be multiplied by `Factor` of a `Name` (country) from `Table2` and loop runs for whole year i.e number of rows in `Table1`. So the first `Value` from `Table1` i.e. `1800` will be distributed according to a `Factor` in `Table2`. Ex. for `UK` it will be `1800*0.003=5.4`
So the result `Table3` suppose to be like this(Given only for two hours):

`Table3`

`Name Date          Year  Month  Hour New_value
UK   01/01/2020     2020   1     0     5.4
BE   01/01/2020     2020   1     0     32.4
DE   01/01/2020     2020   1     0     504
FR   01/01/2020     2020   1     0     774
UK   01/01/2020     2020   1     1     3.9
BE   01/01/2020     2020   1     1     23.4
DE   01/01/2020     2020   1     1     364
FR   01/01/2020     2020   1     1     559`

So, `Value` `1800` will be distributed among all the `Names` then `1300` and so on for the whole year. This is how I have done in nested for loop:

```
Table3 <- matrix(ncol=6, nrow=24)
#This dimension is just for sake of example but varies in my actual solution` 

for (row in 1:nrow(Table1)) {
# This is outer loop which runs over the year
  Value <- Table1[row, "Value"]
  date  <- Table1[row, "Date"]
  Year  <- Table1[row, "Year"]
  Month <- Table1[row, "Month"]
  Hour  <- Table1[row, "Hour"]
  for (r in 1:nrow(Table2))# This is inner loop which runs over the number of Names   
       {
         Name <- Table2[r, "Name"]
         Factor <- Table2[r, "Factor"]
         Table3[row, ]<-c(Name,Value*Factor,date,Year,Month,Hour)
         #Here I want to manipulate and add the data into a new Table3
         r=r+1 # This is increment in name i.e. Table2
        }
         row=row+1
# This is increment in time hour i.e. Table1
}
Table3 <- data.frame(Table3)
```

I am not getting desired output. I am not sure where my loop goes wrong? Could anyone please help me to improve my code? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How do you know which `Factor` to choose? In your example, you multiple `Value` by `Factor` for `Name == "UK"`. Why UK? What about the other countries? Shouldn't `Table3` track which country `Factor` gave rise to `New_value`?

Comment: @ Maurits Evers, as I am using second for loop  `Factor <- Table2[r, "Factor"]` in this line `r` is the row where name is UK and factor 0.003 will be considered. This is what I expect and likewise next row will be selected by increment in row `r=r+1`. I don't know so much about Rstudio but same kind of loop I have done in Matlab code.

Comment: *"I don't know so much about Rstudio"* I guess you mean R (RStudio is an R IDE); I struggle to understand what you mean in your comment. Take a look at the answer below, which might be what you're after. Notice how in the answer below there is a column `Name` that tracks the country where `Factor` came from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your example correctly, there's no need for a loop. As there are no common columns you can use `merge` to recycle `Table2` for each case of `Table1`.  Then it's just arithmetic.

```
Table3 <- merge(Table1, Table2)

Table3$new_value <- with(Table3, value * Factor)

head(Table3[order(Table3$hour),], 10)

         Date year month hour value Name Factor new_value
1  01/01/2020 2020     1    0  1800   UK  0.003       5.4
7  01/01/2020 2020     1    0  1800   BE  0.018      32.4
13 01/01/2020 2020     1    0  1800   DE  0.280     504.0
19 01/01/2020 2020     1    0  1800   FR  0.430     774.0
2  01/01/2020 2020     1    1  1300   UK  0.003       3.9
8  01/01/2020 2020     1    1  1300   BE  0.018      23.4
14 01/01/2020 2020     1    1  1300   DE  0.280     364.0
20 01/01/2020 2020     1    1  1300   FR  0.430     559.0
3  01/01/2020 2020     1    2   400   UK  0.003       1.2
9  01/01/2020 2020     1    2   400   BE  0.018       7.2
```

Data:

```
Table1 <- read.table(text="Date       year  month  hour   value 
01/01/2020  2020   1       0    1800
01/01/2020  2020   1       1    1300
01/01/2020  2020   1       2    400
01/01/2020  2020   1       3    1235
01/01/2020  2020   1       4    120.014
01/01/2020  2020   1       5    812.54", header = TRUE)

Table2 <- read.table(text="Name   Factor
UK      0.003
BE      0.018
DE      0.28
FR      0.43", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: @H 1, Thank you very much. Seems it wok fine, still I have a small doubt I will ask you later when I implement this solution to my big datafram.